# Need help outputting a loop into a text box (javascript)

Tags: loops, for-loop

The last part of  my homework is doing my head in I can't seem to get the out put for my loop into a textbox and output 10 times any help appreciated

```
function btnGenerate_onclick()  
{
// assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 + 8) ;
answer = (Math.pow(2, random));
}

outputTextbox.value = answer
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function btnGenerate_onclick () {
   var answer, random;

   // assign textbox elements to variables for easier access
   var outputTextbox = document.getElementById("txtOutput");

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 24 + 8) ;
       answer = (Math.pow(2, random));
       outputTextbox.value = outputTextbox.value + answer
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it to output ten instances of it in one click

Comment: thats exactly what that code does, here is a working example :: http://jsfiddle.net/kkemple/QMQZV/